# How do I get the Rational Canonical Form from the minimal and characteristic polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let's say I have the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of a matrix and all its invariant factor compositions.  How do I get a rational canonical form matrix from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a matrix $A$ the invariant factors are determined by finding the Smith canonical form equivalent to $(xI - A)$. Let's say $$S(x) = \text{Dg}[1,\ldots,1,f_1(x),\ldots,f_k(x)]$$ is the Smith canonical form. As mentioned elsewhere $f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots,f_k(x)$ are all monic and each lower index monic polynomial divides the following. These are the invariant factors. (Also note that $f_k(x)$ is the minimum polynomial)

Now, it is true that $A$ is similar to Dg$[C(f_1(x)),\ldots,C(f_k(x))]$ where $C(f_i(x))$ indicates the companion matrix associated with $f_i(x)$, but this is not the Rational Canonical Form, to the best of my knowledge, not according to my textbook anyway.

The rational canonical form is derived by finding the *elementary divisors* of $A$. Take any invariant factor $f_i(x)$, then we can write it as $p_1(x)^{ei1}p_2(x)^{ei2}\ldots p_t(x)^{eit}$ where the $p_i(x)$ are distinct, monic and irreducible. These are then the elementary divisors of $A$. The rational canonical form is constructed from these elementary divisors as $$\text{Dg}[\ldots,H(p_1(x)^{ei1}),H(p_2(x)^{ei2}),\ldots,H(p_t(x)^{eit}),\ldots]$$ where $$H(p(x)^e) = \begin{bmatrix} C(p(x)) & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
  N & C(p(x)) & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots &  &  &  & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & N & C(p(x)) \end{bmatrix}.$$ Here $N$ is a matrix that is all zero except for a 1 in the upper right hand corner, and the companion matrix $C(p(x))$ is repeated $e$ times. This is known as a hypercompanion matrix. Note that the rational canonical form reduces to Jordan canonical form when the field is algebraically closed.

Let's look at an example: suppose you have invariant factors $f_1(x) = (x^2 + 4)(x^2 - 3)$ and $f_2(x) = (x^2 + 4)^2(x^2 - 3)^2$, and suppose the field we are considering is $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the elementary divisors are $(x^2 + 4),(x^2 - 3),(x^2 + 4)^2$ and $(x^2 - 3)^2$ and so the rational canonical form is $$\text{Dg}\left [ \begin{bmatrix}0&-4\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&3\\1&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&-4&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&-4\\0&0&1&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&3&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&3\\0&0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}\right ].$$

My source material for this theory: CG Cullen, *Matrices and linear transformations* (2nd edition), the chapter named: Similarity: Part II. There are more examples and in-depth discussion there...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether the terminology is uniform here. The invariant factors are certain monic, non-constant polynomials $f_{i}$ such that
$$
f_{1} \mid f_{2} \mid \dots \mid f_{k},
$$
with $f_{k}$ the minimal polynomial, and $f_{1} f_{2} \dots f_{k}$ the characteristic polynomial.

Take companion matrices $A_{i}$ of each $f_{i}$. Your rational canonical form will be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{1}\\
 & A_{2}\\
 & & A_{3} \\
 & & & \ddots\\
 & & & & A_{k}\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where blanks denote zeros.

Comment: So each individual invariant factor has its own companion matrix?? This is where I've been messing up then. I've been taking 1 large companion matrix of the characteristic polynomial and was unsure why.

Comment: Yes. The [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) gives some more details.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: does it hold generally that 1) $f_1 \mid f_2 \mid \dots \mid f_k$, 2) $f_k = m_A$ 3) $\prod f_i = p_A$ together uniquely determine these factors?

Comment: @gen, I believe that 1 and 3 (with the $f_{i}$ monic) are enough for uniqueness.

Comment: I see, thanks, Andreas Caranti. Do you happen to know what the reason for that is?

Comment: @gen, not a reason that fits in the space of a comment. Jacobson's Basic Algebra I contains a good treatment, for instance.

Comment: Andreas Caranti: thank you — I thought there might be a succint answer. I will check that book.